# Trigger click event by Enter key on div or other non-button in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, keyboard, focus

Just `tabindex="0"` is not enough to trigger click event by focusing on element and then pressing `Enter` key if element is not button/input/link. What else required?

```html
<!--not working, even if the element has focus-->
<div tabindex=0>Trigger click event on me by Enter key!<div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way is to handle the `keydown.enter` event manually. You only get `click` events for free with certain elements (buttons, links, etc) because the browser has special behavior for those elements, with a div that won't happen automatically even though you've made it focusable.

```html
<div tabindex="0" @keydown.enter="handleClick" @click="handleClick">
```

Comment: Got this working on vue3 today.

Answer (score -2):

Use the enter event modifier.

```
<div tabindex=0 @click.enter="doSomething">
```

Comment: This does not work, but `@keydown.enter` does.